# Word 2007 ~ Aspose Skip Empty Cell

Tags: mailmerge, aspose

I am using Aspose with Word for a Mail Merge.

I have a 3x2 table as follows

```
<a>    <b>
<c>    <d>
<e>    <f>
```

However under certain conditions one field might be blank, if this is the case I'd like to ommit the entire cell - i.e. not just have an empty cell. i.e.

```
<a>    <b>
<e>    <d>
       <f>
```

so in the above example c is empty and thus not displayed?

Can this be done?

I have tried IF and blank MERGEFIELDS also NextIf.

Answer (score 1):

@Jon,

You may need to implement the IFieldMergingCallback Interface. The event handler 'FieldMerging' can be used to implement custom control over the mail merge process. For example, you could check the incoming MergeField's value for a 'null' or 'empty string' and then based on this decide to delete the parent Cell. Here is the sample code:

```
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\template.docx");
doc.MailMerge.FieldMergingCallback = new HandleMergeFields();
doc.MailMerge.Execute(new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" },
                        new object[] { "<a>", "<b>", "", "<d>", "<e>", "<f>" });
doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.doc");

private class HandleMergeFields : IFieldMergingCallback
{
    void IFieldMergingCallback.FieldMerging(FieldMergingArgs args)
    {
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(args.Document);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.FieldValue.ToString()))
        {
            Field field = args.Field;
            Cell cell = field.Start.GetAncestor(NodeType.Cell) as Cell;
            // Remove the MergeField
            builder.MoveToMergeField(args.FieldName);
            //Remove the Cell
            cell.Remove();
        }
    } 
    void IFieldMergingCallback.ImageFieldMerging(ImageFieldMergingArgs e)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```